# EmguCV(OpenCV) trying to find a birthmarks (mole)

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, emgucv

i'm trying to get the birthmarks with HoughCircles.

My results so far:
[image]

My code:

```
Mat imgDest = new Mat(imagePath, LoadImageType.Color);
CvtColor(imgDest, imgDest, ColorConversion.Bgr2Gray);
MedianBlur(imgDest, imgDest, 7);
//nice try but not so good... :(
//CvInvoke.Threshold(imgDest, imgDest, 120, 255, ThresholdType.Binary);
//CvInvoke.Canny(imgDest, imgDest, 40, 200);

var circles = CvInvoke.HoughCircles(imgDest, HoughType.Gradient, 1, imgDest.Rows/8, 60, 18);
foreach(var circle in circles)
{
   CvInvoke.Circle(imgDest, new Point((int)circle.Center.X, (int)circle.Center.Y), (int)circle.Radius, new MCvScalar(255, 255, 0), 2);
   imgDest.Save(imageName);                        
}
```

There's something there can i do for get better results?

Answer (score 0):

Please read how Hough transform works for circles. Then you will understand that it is not suitable for this task.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_Hough_Transform

Its basically a brute force method for finding circles. You take every contour pixel and draw a circle around it with a given radius.
You do this for a range of radii. A circle in your image will have the following effect:
For the correct radius all circles of that radius on the perimeter of the circle you want to find will intersect in the center of that circle.

If you don't have a "good" circle in your image this method cannot work as you won't have many intersections its center.

Your moles are barely circles. There are a few where it might work ok but most of them won't give you good or any result (as you have noticed)

I suggest you use some sort of blob detection algorithm (connected component labeling, labeling, blob search, etc.) the web is full of information.

Basic idea:
Separate the mole from the skin by segmentation
Find a group of connected pixels
Calculate features of that group (centroid, perimeter, area,...)